# I wonder if my journal title has grammar error "Starting of my one last year"

Tags: grammar, titles

as i was writing my English journal title, I want to express the meaning of "start of my final(senior) year at school" in a more stylish way. I am not native English speaker and don't have a sense. May I use the title "Starting of my one last year"? I wonder if there is a grammar error or you have a better title suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I think your question will get closed if you don’t explain what you think might be wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better word choice would be The *beginning* of my last year. Or even the *start* of my last year. I can see no reason to enumerate it by adding *one*. It would not be your last two or three years. There is a sensible reason for not using "starting"  but the source escapes me.